# Regex based numeric expression solver

Tags: c#, regex, math

I am making a simple numeric expression solver using regexes and right now I'm working at splitting polynomials into its terms. So this is what I got so far:

```
(.*?)([\+-](.*?))+
```

This doesn't work when negative numbers are involved. Take 3*-2+1 as an example: the terms I get are 3*, -2 and +1, which is obviously wrong.
I thought I could get away with a negative look behind before the sign so that signs preceded by * or / are discarded:

```
(.*?)((?<![\*/])[\+-](.*?))+
```

But this doesn't even work with positive numbers

Suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't think that regex is particularly suitable for parsing such expressions. Why not write your own parser?

Comment: @Oded: I've already done so, but a friend of mine suggested that it is possible to use regexes as well, so I'm trying his approach ;)

Comment: http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Comment: @Oded interesting, I'll keep that in mind. It's just an experiment though, so why not try and see?

Comment: By all means, but do keep our FAQ in mind: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you didn't spend a lot of time creating your own parser ;)

I use this code to evaluate expressions:

```
class Program
{
    public static double Evaluate(string expression)  
    {  
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader("<dummy/>"))
        {
            var navigator = new XPathDocument(stringReader).CreateNavigator();
            expression = Regex.Replace(expression, @"([\+\-\*])", " ${1} "); // add some space
            expression = expression.Replace("/", " div ").Replace("%", " mod ");
            return (double)navigator.Evaluate(string.Format("number({0})", expression));
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Evaluate("3*-2+1"));
    }
}
```

Will output: `-5`

It is based on the [`XPathNavigator.Evaluate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.evaluate.aspx) method. The Regex adds some spaces to the input and then division and modulo symbol are replaced.

Comment: Awesome approach, thank you! But this isn't exactly what I am looking for. This solver will be a sort of thesis for an exam so I'm not allowed to "cheat" like this :) Still, your answer is amazing!